# Car Rental in Italy - Locauto

Tags: car-rentals, italy

Has anyone used the car rental company [Locauto](http://www.locautorent.com/it)? It seems to be an expensive rental car company in Italy, but there are some mixed reviews online, and I'm curious to hear if its a company I should rent a car through. If its not a good one, are there any suggestions?

Comment: Asking for recommendations or suggestions is considered off-topic here, sorry.  Specific questions can be asked as per the [faq], but for now I'm closing this. If it's reworded, it can be flagged and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend something that I've used.
My friends and I rented a car from **AVIS**.

The price was quite reasonable including full insurance. There were free of us in total.
We rented Opel Insignia 2.0 TD for 3 days to get from Stockholm to Copengahen and this cost us 1500 Swedish krones back in May 2012. We also had our own GPS.
It took us less than 15 min to get a car at the local airport.

The price will mainly depend on type of car, insurance type, amount of days, extra accessories (i.e. GPS/cables/etc)

Here are `AVIS locations in Italy` >> [Click Here](http://www.avis.com/car-rental/location/EUR/IT)

You may consider looking at [this site](http://www.rentalcars.com/CountryLandingPage.do;jsessionid=2A1171AD7745BCC93344585581645B48.node143a) as well, as it offers search from a variety of car rental services.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, and that there was a good Avis location in Stockholm doesn't mean anything about Avis in Italy in comparison to other, local car rental agencies.

Comment: Well, I did provide a link to AVIS locations in Italy so that OP can compare prices between AVIS and Locauto. Taking into account that AVIS is one of the top car rental providers not only in Europe, but in the whole world, prices can be cheapier and overall service better. As Idk which car  OP wants to rent, I cannot make demonstrable comparison.